# How to use one object inside of the command object for spring form using annotation controller?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using an object in another class which is used as a command object in form using spring mvc as shown below.

```
public class ManufacturerDO {
int manufacturerID;
String manufacturerName,manufacturerAddress;
}
```

this is an domain object under my command object.My doubt is how to get the fields in this domain object in my spring form.

I'm tried using the followings :

```
<form:select  path="productManufacturer.manufacturerID">
        <c:forEach var="manufacturer" items="${manufacturerList}">
            <form:option value="${manufacturer.manufacturerName}">
                <c:out value="${manufacturer.manufacturerName}" />
            </form:option>
        </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

But getting the following exception:
Invalid property 'productManufacturer' of bean class [com.global.onlineShop.ProductDO]: Value of nested property 'productManufacturer' is null.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1) You should pass a command object instance to the view. I do it this way:

```
public ModelAndView myFunc(ModelAndView model) {
    /* .... */
    ManufacturerDO commandObject = new ManufacturerDO;
    model.addObject("productManufacturer", commandObject);
    return model;
}
```

(However I advice to use autowiring and not to create a new instance in controller action)

2) In JSTL form tag point reference to the commandObject by provided key:

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="productManufacturer">
```

3) When you provide a command object in JSTL form tag you can skip a name of commandObject in the attribute 'path' in all form element JSTL tag so let's write:

```
<form:select path="manufacturerID">
```

4) And of course - do not forget about getters and setters in in a class of a command object.

Comment: I'm using the above method for product which is my command object which contains productmanufacturer object as a field.now i want to access productManufacturer's data fields.how to achieve this?

Comment: Does class ProductDO have getter for its field productManufacturer?

Comment: Yes it has.                                                                      package com.global.onlineShop;

public class ProductDO {
 
 ManufacturerDO productManufacturer;
 
 public ManufacturerDO getProductManufacturer() {
  return productManufacturer;
 }
 public void setProductManufacturer(ManufacturerDO productManufacturer) {
  this.productManufacturer = productManufacturer;
 }
 
}the above is the productDO domain object which is the command object in the form

Comment: Well, if pasted code does not work, I do not have any idea how to make it to work.